# tshark packet capture filter by request url

Tags: rest, packet-capture, tshark

I am trying to only capture packets that contain requests to a certain API endpoint so tried to filter using the following:

```
 tshark -i 2 -f 'port 80' -T pdml http.request.uri contains "/google/"
```

However I keep getting the following error:

```
tshark: A capture filter was specified both with "-f" and with additional 
command-line arguments.
```

Tried removing the -f, but that did not help either. Any suggestions?

eg url: https://testAPI.com/termsearch/google/application

Answer (score 6):

Your [`tshark`](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) command is incorrect.  To specify a Wireshark display filter, you need to use the `-Y` option.

Windows:

```
tshark -i 2 -T pdml -Y "http.request.uri contains \"/google/\""
```

*nix:

```
tshark -i 2 -T pdml -Y 'http.request.uri contains "/google/"'
```